# how do you change the background color with elements: subtle

Tags: css

```
    .subtle {background-color: rgb(0,0,255); }
```

i can't get background color to be blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, like this:

```css
.subtle {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="subtle">content</div>
```